# Why is this proof incorrect?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question was "Let A = {8k: $k \epsilon \Bbb Z$} U {8j + 4: $j \epsilon \Bbb Z$ and B = {$x \epsilon \Bbb Z$: 4|x}. Prove that A = B.

I wrote that A is one of {8k: $k \epsilon \Bbb Z$} so {… -8, 0, 8...}, or {8j + 4: $j \epsilon \Bbb Z$} so {… -4, 0, 12...}
B is {$x \epsilon \Bbb Z$: 4|x}.

Because 8k and 8j + 4 when k, j$\epsilon \Bbb Z$ covers all multiples of 4 because:

4|8k = 4|4(4k) so true. and 4|8j + 4 = 4|4(4j) + 4.

And since B includes all multiples of 4, clearly both cases of A works.

So A = B

Comment: I would not consider this a proof, because it's way way too vague. The standard format of a set equality proof is to start with an element of $A$ and prove it's an element of $B$, and vice-versa. Your starting point is that "A is one of...," which is incorrect; each element of $A$ is in one of the sets you've listed, but $A$ is not either of those two sets. You say that $8k$ and $8j + 4$ cover all multiples of $4$, but your justification is to show that $8k$ and $8j + 4$ *are* multiples of $4$ (so you've proved the converse of what you claim). Those are some of the key problems.

Comment: Might be easier to note that the two sets combined to form $A$ are $$A_e=\{4(2k)\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$$ and $$A_o=\{4(2k+1)\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$$

Comment: Why $4|4(4k)$ and $4|(4j)+4$ ??

Answer (score 1):

Well it is a little bit awkward, I would do it this way:

So if you take any $x\in A$ then $x=8k= 4(2k)$ or $x=8k+4 = 4(2k+1)$ so $x\in B$ and thus $A\subseteq B$ (since $x$ is arbitrary).

Vice versa, take any $y\in B$, then $y=4k$. Write $y=8l+r$ where $r$ is a remanider when $y$ is divided by $8$. Then we get $r = 4k-8l=4(k-2l)$ so $4\mid r$. But $r\in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ so $r=0$ or $r=4$ in both cases $y\in A$, so $B\subseteq A$, so $A=B$.

Comment: I wouldn't quite say it's ok; the argument contained in the OP to show why $B \subset A$ mixes up the statement and its converse.

Answer (score 0):

$n\in A\implies n\in B$ because $4|8k\land 4|8k+4$

and

$n\in B\implies n\in A$ because $4|n\implies n=4k\implies 4k=8k'\lor 4k=8k'+4$ ($k$ is even or odd).

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}{\bf Hint}\ \ \ \Bbb Z &\,=\, 2\Bbb Z \,\cup\, 1\!+\!2\Bbb Z\\
\Rightarrow\   4\Bbb Z &\,=\, 8\Bbb Z\, \cup\, 4\!+\!8\Bbb Z
\end{align}$